# How to retrieve a value from <a> tag

Tags: jquery, html

How to retrieve a value from `<a>` tag.

```
 <a href="" class="test" id="content">Hai</a>
```

From the above code i need to extract the value(test or content) either from **class** or **id** and want to store the extracted value in db using **php**.

Comment: wat code?? however, $('elementId or .ElementClassName).html() shd do for you

Comment: `<a>` tag doesn't have values either you use `.html()`, `.text()` or `.attr()` to fulfil your requirements.

Answer (score 4):

```
$('#content').attr('href'); // gives you the link
$('#content').attr('class'); //gives you the class name
```

Like this you can access any attribute.

Answer (score 2):

still confused what value u need to extract... here is some example

```
 $('#content').attr('class'); //extract class by id
 $('#content').attr('href');  //extract href by id
 $('#content').html();  //extract value in <a> tag
```

use `ajax` or `post` if u want to store the value in db..

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

**JQUERY**

```
 $.post("test.php", { data: $('#content').attr('class')}, //assuming you want class value to be posted.
   function(data) {
      alert("succesfully inserterd");
 });
```

**PHP test.php**

```
 $value= $_POST['data'];
 //do your stuff like insreting it to db
```

Answer (score 0):

The .attr() method gets the attribute value for only the first element in the matched set. To get the value for each element individually, use a looping construct such as jQuery's .each() or .map() method.

For more details refer to this [link](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(".test").live("click",function(){
  alert($(this).attr('class'));
});
</script>

<a href="#" class="test" id="content">Test</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
 //with javascript
 document.getElementById('content').innerHTML;

//with jQuery
$('#content').html();
```

Answer (score -1):

Another way is assign value to value attribute

And here is sample code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(".test").live("click",function(){
    alert($(this).attr('value'));
});
</script>
<a href="#" class="test" id="content" value="Test">Test</a>
```

try it!

Comment: assign ??? what do u mean... this is not gonna work..

Comment: @bipen I mean use value attribute and put the value you want to retrieve  and It works f9!

Comment: value attribute in <a> tag.... have u tried this yourself????

Comment: @bipen yeah I have tried & it works

Comment: @Sandip `<a>` tags doesn't have value attribute as per valid markup. Think again about it.

Comment: @jai yeah I know ,But if you apply that It works like charm!

Comment: This is absolutely wrong.

Comment: @undefined the way it works is f9 but as I explained in answer it is just a another way to access the value that's it.

Comment: @Sandip i think value is not a valid markup. The .attr() method gets the attribute value for only the first element in the matched set.